# sm-r730-gear-s2 : Satellite info api's returns LOCATION_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, nmea, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-native-app

I wanted to get nmea and/or satellite information from Samsung gear s2. The device is capable of standalone GPS.

I followed the instruction on developer site and I am using gps_status_get_nmea and gps_status_foreach_satellites_in_view api's for the same

I get the location service state as LOCATION_SERVICE_ENABLED after starting the location manager.

The API returns LOCATION_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, is there some priviledge I am missing. I have already added /location in the priviledge.

I am able to get the lat, long, altitude and other information using  location_manager_get_location api but nmea and other satellite information returns error LOCATION_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Any help would be appreciated.

More details on Samsung forum.. I also asked there but no luck :(

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=288620&startId=zzzzz~

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for downvote ? Let me know I can clarify the question more. It will be great if someone can help

Comment: I'm facing this very same problem trying to get the satellite info from a Gear S3. I tried to get the NMEA string and I got the same error too: that NOT_SUPPORTED answer.  I added one entry into the Samsung forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but as the Gear S3 doesn't support the GPS and Satellite Functions, despite what the API docs say,  I suspect the gear S2 doesn't either. You can find out by checking system features before you run your app. Note that when working in Tizen Studio debug the emulators don't in any event support any of the GPS and Satellite functions.